# Investigate html/js issues on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, debugging, emulation

I'm working on a web-app, and there are several issues(HTML markup and js functionality) that are reproduced only on Ipad and iPhone. The problem is - I don't have any ios devices. How can I reproduce, and then debug (like I do in browsers web developer tools) those issues on windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have iMac, MacBook or any Mac OS device you can use **Xcode** application and run real device simulator.

If you don't have such device you can use online services like https://www.browserstack.com

[image]